Exchange Hybrid won't send to mailboxes created in EOL
We have an Exchange 2019 Hybrid server to remote mail-enable our AD users and send outbound to our mailboxes from certain legacy apps. Though our users are all AD-bound, we create some mailboxes (e.g. shared ones) directly in EOL/M365 (aka no AD object).
The hybrid server reliably sends mail to all of our AD-bound remote mailboxes, but as soon as we change the recipient to a shared mailbox created in EOL directly (no AD object), we get something like this:
<550 4.4.7 QUEUE.Expired; message expired in unreachable destination queue. Reason: A matching connector cannot be found to route the external recipient>
Also, for what it's worth, I noticed in the message tracking logs that when we address to "user@ourcustomdomain.com" the successful deliveries do a routing source resolve to "user@ourtenant.mail.onmicrosoft.com".  Our shared mailboxes are created in EOL directly and would only have "sharedmailbox@ourcustomdomain.com" by default.
As I was writing this up, I tried adding a secondary SMTP of "sharedmailbox@ourtenant.mail.onmicrosoft.com" through EOL, and sending another test message, but the hybrid host still considers the shared mailbox as an external recipient.
If anyone has experienced this and has a suggestion, I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Hi, in hybrid it's bestpractice to have the management all done on the AD, why it was created on M365 directly ? I seen case like you that can bring sync problem afterhand with the adsync. Is adsync working correctly for your tenant ? I seen case where in a hybrid, that the admin create another mailbox online only, but it's for other email alias/upn outside of the scoop of the adsync, like if you have two domain in m365, and only one in your onprem exchange.

Yes, Entra Sync is working correctly; to clarify we do not have any on-prem mailboxes and never did; we came from a non-Exchange environment and installed the Hybrid in-house just to have the GUI to manage the AD users' mail attributes and identities/pwds.  We never had shared folders, or contacts, etc.  We only sync AD users, computers and security groups.  We don't even want to receive inbound mail on the hybrid server from outside; we want to send out to our custom M365 domain from internal legacy services that can't handle current (or future) changes to SMTP auth requirements in M365.

The issue was the send connector.  (This host had replaced a 2016 Hybrid host)
During the course of hybrid setup, two send connectors were auto-created.
Send connector 1:

Delivery: MX record associated with recipient domain
Scope: smtp address space = ourtenant.mail.onmicrosoft.com
source server: [internal hybrid host]

Send connector 2 (which we updated to get it working):

Delivery: route through smart host: oursmarthost.mail.onmicrosoft.com
Scope: smtp address space = *
source server: [internal hybrid host] <-- this was missing

When we emailed user@ourcustomdomain.com it was forcing resolution to user@ourtenant.mail.onmicrosoft.com. For shared mailboxes where sharedmailbox@ourcustomdomain.com did not have another address, this second send connector was now able to be used to send out.
There are other options such as merging the send connectors, but we are leaving these separate for clarity and future understanding.
More details on this and related settings can be found here:
https://practical365.com/exchange-2016-smtp-relay-connector/
Hope this helps someone else (or me, again, in a year!)
